# problem extracting an app.asar file using the asar command

Tags: electron, asar

I am new to Electron and want to make (at first) a sample javascript change in the Slack Electron app.  I am here on a Mac OSX:

```
/Applications/Slack.app/Contents/Resources
```

and run the following:

```
asar extract app.asar ~/Desktop/src
```

And then without even making a change run:

```
asar pack ~/Desktop/src app.asar
```

The "re-packed" file is significantly larger:

```
    -rw-r--r--   1 oliverwilliams  staff  28336486 Apr 21 03:25 app.asar
    -rw-r--r--   1 oliverwilliams  staff   8175963 Mar 21 13:26 app.asar.original
```

and Slack will not start.  Reverting back to the original file, Slack runs again.

Obviously I need to crawl before I can walk.  What needs to be done here?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried unpacking and re-packing an *.asar file (merely changing 4 small system tray icons in png format) in linux, using npm / npr extract/pack commands. The output file was far smaller (and broken of course). I had to use 7zip with asar plugin at the end. :-(